# Did Jacob and Manoah meet the same angel of the Lord?

Tags: genesis, judges

> Genesis 32:29
> Jacob said, "Please tell me your name." But he replied, "Why do you ask my name?" Then he blessed him there.

> Judges 13:17 Then Manoah inquired of the angel of the Lord, “What is your name, so that we may honor you when your word comes true?”18
> He replied, "Why do you ask my name? It is beyond understanding."

Did Jacob and Manoah meet the same person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two accounts to compere:

**1.  Jacob's Wrestling Partner, Gen 32:22-31**

- In V28 Jacob is described as wrestling with God
- In V30 Jacob says that he has seen God "face to face"
- In V29 Jacob asks for and receives a blessing from God who changes his name from Jacob to Israel.

**2. Manoah & Wife's "Angel of the LORD", Judges 13**

- In V2, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, etc, we read, "Angel of the LORD"
- In V6, 8, we read, "Man of God"
- In V9, we read, "Angel of God"
- In V22, the same person is described as "God".

Thus, it appears to be the same person in both cases.  "Angel of the LORD" is sometimes the LORD Himself as per Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, Rev 8:3-5, 10:1-10, 18:1, 20:1-4.

A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely yes. Just like the angel of the Lord (the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ) met with Hagar at Genesis 16:7, also with Abraham at various places, Genesis 17:1-2 and Genesis 22. He also appeared to others in the Old Testament. And as a side note the angel of the Lord never appears in the New Testament as the angel of the Lord.

Notice from Genesis 32:29 the cross reference to Genesis 35-9-15. "Then GOD appeared to Jacob AGAIN when he came from Paddansram, and He/God blessed him etc. Notice how God changed Jacob's name to Israel.

God also told Jacob to be fruitful and multiply and told him He would give the land to Jacob just like God did to Abraham and Isaac.

Getting back to the angel of the Lord appearing to Manoah and Manoah ask the angel of the Lord his name at verse 18, "But the angel of the Lord said to him, "Why do you ask my name, seeing it is "wonderful." I cross referenced this to Isaiah 9:6, "And His name will be called "Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God." One can make what they want out of it but it is rather interesting.

The following is what Keil and Delhzsch say on the matter.

"Just as the angel of Jehovah, when asked by Manoah what was his name (Judges 13:18), replied פּלי (פּלאי), and indicated thereby his divine nature - a nature incomprehensible to mortal men; so here the God-given ruler is also pele', a phenomenon lying altogether beyond human conception or natural occurrence. Not only is this or that wonderful in Him; but He Himself is throughout a wonder - παραδοξασμός, as Symmachus renders it. The second name if yō‛ētz, counsellor, because, by virtue of the spirit of counsel which He possesses (Isaiah 11:2), He can always discern and given counsel for the good of His nation."

So yes, "THE" angel of the Lord met with both Jacob and Manoah.